# PHP: When to maintain object backlinks

Tags: php, domain-driven-design

From time to time I have read about the need to maintain back-links between domain objects, however I have never come across the need to do so.  I'm wondering if it is something to do with my coding style, or the fact that I work with PHP.

By way of example, consider an application that runs a veterinary practice.  Owners have a connection to a collection of animals (their pets).  Veterinarians also have a connection to a collection of animals (their patients).  When the animal's veterinarian changes, there are two ways I could write the method.  Firstly, the simple method:

```
class Animal {
    //
    public function changeVet(Veterinarian $vet) {
        $this->vet = $vet;
    }
}
```

Secondly, a more complex method that maintains backlinks:

```
class Animal {    
    //
    public function changeVet(Veterinarian $vet) {
        $vet->addPatient($this);
        $this->vet->removePatient($this);
        $this->vet = $vet;
    }
}
```

Obviously the second method is much more complex, but I have never needed to use it.  I can see the requirement if I was writing a Java application where the in-memory model is persisted between requests, but that doesn't happen with PHP. Am I missing something?

As far as I can see, the only downside of not maintaining back links with PHP is that the developer needs to be aware of how things are persisted.  For example, in the case above, if I needed to iterate a veterinarian's collection of patients in the same request that I was using to change a pet's veterinarian, I would need to reload the collection (rather than following a link).  This happens only rarely.

Answer (score 2):

It's almost always possible to create a design without bi-directional associations.

**Unidirectional designs are much better than bi-directional ones, because coupling between classes is smaller. As a consequence, the design can be adapted and refactored more easily, and testing is simpler.**

Comment: Interesting.  Where can I find out more about this?

Comment: Any decent book about object-oriented design should do. I don't know a good one that uses PHP as example language, though. Also, take a look at the [Solid Principles](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SOLID_%28object-oriented_design%29).

Comment: @KimPrince Eric Evans touches on that in the DDD blue book, though I can't remember which chapter.

Answer (score 0):

When to maintain backlinks? When your business rules require you need them.

Your example with the backlink has one maybe important side effect: If the owner of the pet decides to change the vet, the vet knows he lost a patient.

Unfortunately your example lacks the depth to explain the requirements based on business rules. It's easy to create a situation where you'd need backlinks, but using objects resembling an actual business probably isn't the best.

Your first example states that an animal has a vet, and that the vet can change. You don't say anything about the vet itself. The second example states the same, and also says that the vet has the animal as patient. So this example only ever applies if your business deals with the patients of vets. Anything else (like dealing with managing animals of users, including their vet) will never require the vet to know about their patients. And even if you are dealing with vet's patients, you probably don't change the vet on an animal, you add a new animal to the specific vet because that's what happened in the real world (so no `changeVet()`, only `addPatient()`).

The only situation where managing user's animals and vet's together would be if you have a business about multiple vets and animals, like an insurance company. In this case, knowing which animal is treated by which vet may be important, so switching vets may be a business case.

TL;DR: Maintain backlinks if you know you have to. Avoid if not.